# C Battleship Game Linked List print_node function

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I've been working on a battleship program in C for a class and I am having trouble with my print_node function returning the values from my head node (currentState, ship_type, charInput etc.). Each time I run it, it compiles however it always outputs "0". I'm hoping a second set of eyes could help me figure this out. Thank you, and forgive me for the messy code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 10

typedef struct Node{
char currentState;
char ship_type[20];
char charInput;
int intInput;
struct Node* next;
}Node;

char** initialization(){
    int i, j, k, row, col;
    char **board = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*SIZE);
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        board[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
            board[i][j] = '-';
        }
    }

    //place the first ship 
    //the direction of placement is hard coded 
    //you can change it if you want
    bool placed1 = false;
    while(placed1 == false){
        row = rand()%10;
        col = rand()%10; 
        if(row+1 < 10 && row-1 >= 0){ 
            if((board[row][col] = '-') && 
                (board[row+1][col] = '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'D';
                    board[row+1][col] = 'D';
                    placed1 = true; 
            }
            else if((board[row][col] == '-') && 
                (board[row-1][col] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'D'; 
                    board[row-1][col] = 'D';
                    placed1 = true;
            }
        }
    }

    //place the second ship
    bool placed2 = false;
    while (placed2 == false){
        row = rand()%10;
        col = rand()%10;
        if((row+1 < 10 && row+2 < 10) && 
            (row-1 >= 0 && row-2 >= 0) && 
            (col+1 < 10 && col+2 < 10) && 
            (col-1 >= 0 && col-2 >= 0)){
            if((board[row][col] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col+1] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col+2] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'C';
                    board[row][col+1] = 'C';
                    board[row][col+2] = 'C';
                    placed2 = true;
            }
            else if((board[row][col] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col-1] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col-2] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'C';
                    board[row][col-1] = 'C';
                    board[row][col-2] = 'C';
                    placed2 = true;
            }
            else if((board[row][col] == '-') && 
                (board[row+1][col] == '-') && 
                (board[row+2][col] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'C';
                    board[row+1][col] = 'C';
                    board[row+2][col] = 'C';
                    placed2 = true;
            }
            else if((board[row][col] == '-') &&
                (board[row-1][col] == '-') &&
                (board[row-2][col] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'C';
                    board[row-1][col] = 'C';
                    board[row-2][col] = 'C';
                    placed2 = true;
            }
        }
    }

    //place the third ship
    bool placed3 = false;
    while (placed3 == false){
        row = rand()%10;
        col = rand()%10;
        if((row+1 < 10 && row+2 < 10) &&
            (row-1 >= 0 && row-2 >= 0) && 
            (col+1 < 10 && col+2 < 10) && 
            (col-1 >= 0 && col-2 >= 0)){
            if((board[row][col] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col+1] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col+2] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'S';
                    board[row][col+1] = 'S';
                    board[row][col+2] = 'S';
                    placed3 = true;
            }
            else if((board[row][col] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col-1] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col-2] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'S';
                    board[row][col-1] = 'S';
                    board[row][col-2] = 'S';
                    placed3 = true;
            }
            else if((board[row][col] =='-') && 
                (board[row+1][col] == '-') && 
                (board[row+2][col] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'S';
                    board[row+1][col] = 'S';
                    board[row+2][col] = 'S';
                    placed3 = true;
            }
            else if((board[row][col] == '-') && 
                (board[row-1][col] == '-') && 
                (board[row-2][col] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'S';
                    board[row-1][col] = 'S';
                    board[row-2][col] = 'S';
                    placed3 = true;
            }
        }
    }

    bool placed4 = false;
    while (placed4 == false){
        row = rand()%10;
        col = rand()%10;
        if((row+1 < 10 && row+2 < 10 && row+3 < 10) &&
            (row-1 >= 0 && row-2 >= 0 && row-3 >= 0) && 
            (col+1 < 10 && col+2 < 10 && col+3 < 10) && 
            (col-1 >= 0 && col-2 >= 0 && col-3 >= 0)){
            if((board[row][col] == '-') && 
                 (board[row+1][col] == '-') &&
                 (board[row+2][col] == '-') &&
                 (board[row+3][col] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'B';
                    board[row+1][col] = 'B';
                    board[row+2][col] = 'B';
                    board[row+3][col] = 'B';
                    placed4 = true;
            }
            else if((board[row][col] == '-') &&
                 (board[row-1][col] == '-') &&
                 (board[row-2][col] == '-') &&
                 (board[row-3][col] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'B';
                    board[row-1][col] = 'B';
                    board[row-2][col] = 'B';
                    board[row-3][col] = 'B';
                    placed4 = true;
            }
            else if((board[row][col] == '-') &&
                 (board[row][col+1] == '-') &&
                 (board[row][col+2] == '-') &&
                 (board[row][col+3] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'B';
                    board[row][col+1] = 'B';
                    board[row][col+2] = 'B';
                    board[row][col+3] = 'B';
                    placed4 = true;
            }
            else if((board[row][col] == '-') &&
                 (board[row][col-1] == '-') &&
                 (board[row][col-2] == '-') &&
                 (board[row][col-3] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'B';
                    board[row][col-1] = 'B';
                    board[row][col-2] = 'B';
                    board[row][col-3] = 'B';
                    placed4 = true;
            }
        }
    }

    bool placed5 = false;
    while (placed5 == false){
        row = rand()%10;
        col = rand()%10;
        if((row+1 < 10 && row+2 < 10 && row+3 < 10 && row+4 < 10) &&
            (row-1 >= 0 && row-2 >= 0 && row-3 >= 0 && row-4 >= 0) && 
            (col+1 < 10 && col+2 < 10 && col+3 < 10 && col+4 < 10) &&
            (col-1 >= 0 && col-2 >= 0 && col-3 >= 0 && col-4 >= 0)){
            if((board[row][col] == '-') &&
               (board[row+1][col] == '-') &&
               (board[row+2][col] == '-') &&
               (board[row+3][col] == '-') &&
               (board[row+4][col] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'R';
                    board[row+1][col] = 'R';
                    board[row+2][col] = 'R';
                    board[row+3][col] = 'R';
                    board[row+4][col] = 'R';
                    placed5 = true;
            }
            else if((board[row][col] == '-') &&
                 (board[row-1][col] == '-') &&
                 (board[row-2][col] == '-') &&
                 (board[row-3][col] == '-') &&
                 (board[row-4][col] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'R';
                    board[row-1][col] = 'R';
                    board[row-2][col] = 'R';
                    board[row-3][col] = 'R';
                    board[row-4][col] = 'R';
                    placed5 = true;
            }
            else if((board[row][col] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col+1] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col+2] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col+3] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col+4] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'R';
                    board[row][col+1] = 'R';
                    board[row][col+2] = 'R';
                    board[row][col+3] = 'R';
                    board[row][col+4] = 'R';
                    placed5 = true;
            }
            else if((board[row][col] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col-1] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col-2] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col-3] == '-') && 
                (board[row][col-4] == '-')){
                    board[row][col] = 'R';
                    board[row][col-1] = 'R';
                    board[row][col-2] = 'R';
                    board[row][col-3] = 'R';
                    board[row][col-4] = 'R';
                    placed5 = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return board;
}

void update_state(char* state, char ** board, char character, int col){
    int row;
       char shipType[20];
        row = character % 65;
        if(board[row][col] == '-'){
            strcpy(state, "MISS");
        }
        else{
            strcpy(state, "HIT!");
            /* add code to change the board to indicate 
            * that shot hit , for example you could change 
            * the corresponding letter back to '-'.
            * but before this, you need to record the letter
            * and corresponding ship type.
            */ //COMPLETED
            char shipChar = board[row][col];
            if(shipChar == 'R'){
                strcpy(shipType,"Carrier");
                printf("%s", shipType);
            }
            else if(shipChar == 'B'){
                strcpy(shipType,"Battleship");
                printf("%s", shipType);
            }
            else if(shipChar == 'S'){
                strcpy(shipType,"Submarine");
                printf("%s", shipType);
            }
            else if(shipChar == 'C'){
                strcpy(shipType,"Cruiser");
                printf("%s", shipType);
            }
            else if(shipChar == 'D'){
                strcpy(shipType,"Destroyer");
                printf("%s", shipType);
            }
            printf("%c", shipChar);
            board[row][col] = '-'; //set target coordinates to '-'
        }

        /* add code to update temp node's attributes (i.e
        * hit or miss, ship type, then insert the temp node
        * the node into the linked list. 
        * You may need to write the insert node function 
        * (you can refer to the insert node function in lab5 
        * handout )
        */
        struct Node *head, *tail;
        head = tail = NULL;
        insert_node(&head, &tail, col, row, *state, shipType);
        print_node(head);

    //check if game is over //completed
    int m = 0;
    int k, l;
    for(k = 0; k < SIZE; k++){
        for(l = 0; l < SIZE; l++){
            if(board[k][l] == '-'){
                m++;
                if(m >= 100){
                    strcpy(state, "GAME OVER!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int accept_input(char * c, int * i){ 
    bool flag = true;
    do{
        printf("Enter a letter A-J and number 0-9 ex. B4 - enter Z0 to end\n");
        int size = scanf(" %c%d", c, i);
        if(size != 2){
            printf("INVALID INPUT\n");
            continue;
        }
        *c = toupper(*c);
        if(*c == 'Z' && *i == 0)
            break;
        if (*c < 65 || *c > 74)
            printf("INVALID INPUT\n");
        else if (*i <0 || *i >9)
            printf("INVALID INPUT\n");
        else
            flag = false;
    }while(flag);
}
/*
char currentState;
char ship_type;
*/

void insert_node(struct Node **h, struct Node **t, int x, char y, char* state, char shipTyp){
    //create new node with value given by int x, y
    struct Node *temp;
    if ((temp = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node))) == NULL){
        printf("Node Allocation Failed \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //space for node obtained, copy values into node
    temp->charInput = y; //store user character input
    temp->intInput = x; //store user number input
    temp->currentState = state; //store state
    temp->ship_type[20] = shipTyp; //store shipType
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (*h == NULL){
        //list is empty if so
        *h = *t = temp;
    }
    else{ //list isnt empty, use *t to add node at the end
        (*t)->next = temp;
        *t = (*t)->next;
    }

}
//will be converted to a write to file function
void print_node(struct Node *h){
    if(h == NULL){
        printf("The list is empty.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Values in the list are: \n");
        while(h != NULL) {
            printf("%c\n", h->charInput);
            printf("%s\n", h->ship_type);
            h = h->next;
        }
    }
}

void display_state(char* state, char** board){
    int i, j;
    printf("\n**** %s ****\n", state);
    printf("  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n");
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        printf("%c ", 65+i);
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

int teardown(char ** board){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        free(board[i]);
    free(board); 

    /* add code below to traverse the linkded list
    * you should create a log file name "log.txt"
    * traverse each node in the linked list, and 
    * write the information in each node into "log.txt"
    * Each line should follow this format:
    *   Fired at A1. Hit - Carrier.
    *   Fired at C2. Miss. 
    * You may refer to the print_list function in lab5
    * handout.
    * In addition, remember to free the nodes of the
    * linked list.
    */

    return 0;
}



int main(void){
    //
    void print_node(struct Node*);
    void insert_node(struct Node**, struct Node**, int, char, char*, char);
    srand(time(NULL));
    char** board;
    char state[] = "GAME START";
    char flag[] = "GAME OVER!";
    char character;
    int integer;
    /* declare a linked list below*/ //COMPLETED
    //struct Node* head = NULL;
    //struct Node* second = NULL;
    //head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    //second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));


    board = initialization();
    do{ 
        display_state(state, board);
        if(display_state)
        /*modify the accept_input function 
        * accept input function should return 
        * a temp node, which stores the current valid
        * input (i.e. character and letter)
        */
        accept_input(&character, &integer);
        if(character == 'Z' && integer == 0)
            break;
        /*modify the update_state function 
        * update_state function should accept 
        * the head node of linked list and the 
        * temp node
        */
        update_state(state, board, character, integer);
    } while((character != 'Z' || integer != 0) && strcmp(state, flag) );

    /*modify the teardown function 
    * tear_down function should accept 
    * a head node of linked list
    */
    teardown(board);
    return 0;
}

//modularize insertNode, etc. inito own functions
```

Comment: It's not clear which compiler you're using, but whatever it is, *always* turn on max warnings. Sometimes they don't tell you anything, but it's common they will point out trouble areas or even outright bugs.  If you're using gcc, then `gcc -W -Wall game.c` then look into each one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
void print_node(struct Node *h) {
     if(h != null){
        printf("%c\n", h->charInput);
        printf("%s\n", h->ship_type);
        print_node(h->next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you call your print function in update_state, which means you are storing to the file every move.

number 1, you need to append to the file and not write
change:

```
fPTR = fopen("log.txt", "w");
```

to:

```
fPTR = fopen("log.txt", "a");
```

And change your write function to:

```
//will be converted to a write to file function
void print_node(struct Node *h, FILE *fPTR){
    printf("got this far");

    if (h == NULL) {
        printf("THE LIST IS EMPTY\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nThis move was:\n");
        printf("%c\n", h->charInput);
        printf("%s\n", h->ship_type);
        printf("%d\n", h->intInput);
        printf("%s\n", h->currentState);
        fprintf(fPTR, "Fired at %c%d. %s - %s. \n", h->charInput, h->intInput, h->currentState, h->ship_type);
    fclose(fPTR);
    }
}
```

This is assuming your linkedist head is created correctly

EDIT: This code gets the last move played and adds it to the file, you will have to delete the file whenever you start a new game.